# How to group and merge list in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

For example, I have the follwing list:

```
data:[
    {
        year:2017,
        price:10
    },
    {
        year:2017,
        price:19
    },
    {
        year:2020,
        price:15
    },
    {
        year:2021,
        price:100
    },
    {
        year:2020,
        price:20
    }
]
```

My purpose is to merge the price of list by the same year.
As the example list show: the result need to be:

```
data:[
    {
        year:2017,
        price:29
    },
    {
        year:2020,
        price:35
    },
    {
        year:2021,
        price:100
    }
]
```

Is there any way to achieve it quickly? Like `groupingby`,`map`...?

Comment: You got the right track. `groupBy` and `map` are the two steps, but you also need `reduce`. You first group by the common factor (year) and then map reduce the resulting groups.

Comment: Could you help me? I have difficult to use the kotlin method correctly.I have search it for hours..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some overhead to make this compile.

The essence is to group all Year-Price-Tuples by year, then reduce each group to one element (by summing up the prices).
I also added a conversion back to a list, and sorted by year.

```kotlin
data class Sales(val year: Int, val price: Int)

val myList = listOf(
    Sales(2017, 10),
    Sales(2017, 19),
    Sales(2020, 15),
    Sales(2021, 100),
    Sales(2020, 20),
)

fun main () {
    val reduced = myList.groupBy({ it.year }, { it })
          .mapValues { it.value.reduce{ left, right ->
              Sales(left.year, (left.price + right.price)) } }
          .values
          .sortedBy { it.year }
    reduced.forEach { println("${it.year}: ${it.price}") }
}
```

This yields:

```
2017: 29
2020: 35
2021: 100
```

Comment: This will create multiple in-flight data structures which will reduce its performance for large data sets

Comment: @mightyWOZ While that is true, OPs desired result requires all elements to be processed. A pipeline, stream, or other structure that operates lazy cannot be significantly faster, especially since most operations require all previous operations to finish. (sortedBy, groupBy). For very large data sets, memory usage could be reduced a bit I guess.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it by using this also

```
data class Sales(
    val year: Int,
    val price: Int
)

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val salesByYear = listOf(
            Sales(2017, 10),
            Sales(2017, 19),
            Sales(2020, 15),
            Sales(2021, 100),
            Sales(2020, 20),
            Sales(2016, 500),
            Sales(2021, 320)
        )
        
        var list = ArrayList<Sales>();

        
        salesByYear.groupBy(Sales::year).mapValues { entry ->
            list.add(Sales(entry.key, entry.value.map { it.price }.sumBy { it })) }

        println(list)
    }
```

Output will be as follows

```
 [Sales(year=2017, price=29),
 Sales(year=2020, price=35), 
Sales(year=2021, price=420), 
Sales(year=2016, price=500)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define a `grouping` on basis of `year` and then perfrom a aggregation reduction on all group elements

```
// ListElementType is the type of objects stored in the list
yourList.groupingBy { it.year }.aggregate{key:Int, accumulator:Long?, element:ListElementType, first:Boolean ->
        accumulator?.plus(element.price)?.toLong() ?: element.price.toLong()
}.toList()
```